# How to set the 'where' clause for a field with comma-seperated values?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT 
  ListProperty.*,PropertyType.ptype as PType,PropertyType.category as PCategoryi,locations.location as PLocation 
FROM 
  ListProperty,PropertyType,locations,ListPropertySortData 
WHERE 
  (ListProperty.ptid=PropertyType.ptid AND ListProperty.locid=locations.locid) 
  AND ListProperty.lpid IN (SELECT lpid FROM ListPropertyMore WHERE ListProperty.locid LIKE '%12,18%') 
  AND ListPropertySortData.lpid=ListProperty.lpid 
  AND expdate>=CURDATE() 
  AND status='T';
```

I need to output for locid for 12 and 18 both

Comment: You shouldn't be storing comma separated values in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use `FIND_IN_SET` like this:

```
SELECT 
  ListProperty.*,
  PropertyType.ptype as PType,
  PropertyType.category as PCategoryi,
  locations.location as PLocation 
FROM 
  ListProperty,PropertyType,
  locations,
  ListPropertySortData 
WHERE 
  (
    ListProperty.ptid=PropertyType.ptid 
    AND ListProperty.locid=locations.locid
  ) 
  AND ListProperty.lpid IN 
  (
      select 
        lpid 
      from 
        ListPropertyMore 
      WHERE FIND_IN_SET (ListProperty.locid, '12,18')
  ) 
  AND ListPropertySortData.lpid=ListProperty.lpid 
  AND expdate>=CURDATE() AND status='T'
```

Reference:

- [FIND_IN_SET(str,strlist)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the OR operator.

```
WHERE (ListProperty.locid like '%12%' OR ListProperty.locid like '%18%')
```

Answer (score 0):

For `locid` as both 12 and 18, Use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses:

Try this:

```
SELECT PropertyType.ptype as PType,PropertyType.category as PCategoryi,locations.location as PLocation 
FROM ListProperty,PropertyType,locations,ListPropertySortData 
WHERE (ListProperty.ptid=PropertyType.ptid AND ListProperty.locid=locations.locid) 
  AND ListProperty.lpid IN (select lpid from ListPropertyMore WHERE ListProperty.locid IN (12,18) ) 
  AND ListPropertySortData.lpid=ListProperty.lpid 
  AND expdate>=CURDATE() AND status='T' 
GROUP BY PropertyType.ptype,PropertyType.category,locations.location
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ListProperty.lpid)=2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the IN operand better for this;

`AND ListProperty.lpid IN (select lpid from ListPropertyMore WHERE ListProperty.locid  IN (12,18) )`

but to your method,  You've it backwards, and I would add commas to the beginning and ends as you will get partial matches where the added commas make it more distinct: 
`AND ListProperty.lpid IN (select lpid from ListPropertyMore WHERE ',12,18,' LIKE CONCAT('%,',ListProperty.locid,',%' )`

Arion's answer is easier than "manually" working it out like above, using the same CSV scheme.